# Read MySQL JSON column array as rows

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, mysql-json

I have a table

```
X

 - id
 - name (eg: 'testing')
 - array_column_name (eg: ["value1","value2"])
```

I want a query that will return the following output.

```
_____________________
| column1 | column2 |
| testing | value1  |
| testing | value2  |
|_________|_________|
```

Essentially what I need is to convert the array to rows.

I tried using

```
SELECT name, JSON_EXTRACT(@'array_column_name', '*') FROM X;
```

But I am not sure what to put as the second parameter of the `JSON_EXTRACT` since my columns contain a plain array instead array of objects.

Comment: Can you put an example of your json?

Comment: @Vixed I already have an example in the first codeblock. ["value1","value2"]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL >= 8.0.4, you can use [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table), otherwise, to achieve what you need will be somewhat less simple:

```sql
SELECT
  `X`.`name` `column1`,
  `der`.`column2`
FROM
  `X`,
  JSON_TABLE(
    `array_column_name`,
    '$[*]'
    COLUMNS(
      `column2` VARCHAR(255) PATH '$'
    )
  ) `der`;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aAfcCNR3fQTbD3Epvg2RmK/2).